# Accidentally deleted .desktop entry, how do I recreate it?

Tags: unity, .desktop

I was trying to create my own desktop environment and was working with sudo nautilus and i accidentally deleted .desktop entry for ubuntu 3d, help needed

Comment: Your case is just a very good example of Why you shouldn't use nautilus with root power

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean `/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop` file.

Here is the contents of that file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu
Comment=This session logs you into Ubuntu
Exec=gnome-session --session=ubuntu
TryExec=unity
Icon=
Type=Application
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-3.0
```

Save it to `/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop` and you have your session back. For editing purpose, you can use the TTY logins via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> shortcut.